# Why do programming languages not let you use a try block without a catch block?

Tags: javascript, exceptions

Why do languages demand catch blocks when they aren't needed?

The compiler or parser complains with this code:

```
try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
}
```

But it is OK with this code:

```
try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
} catch(e) {}
```

I don't need the catch block.

I'm using JavaScript if it matters.

**Update Example Code:**

```
// setting defaults ahead of try - no need for a catch block
var setting = 10;
var myRegEx = "/123/g";
var supportsRegEx2 = false;

try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
    setting = 20;
    myRegEx = "/123/gm";
    supportsRegEx2 = true;
}
```

**The long story**
I'm working in an browser like environment where new API's are introduced frequently. Some API's are silently introduced, no documentation but available.

If I want to use a new API I can set a minimum-version flag in my manifest. But if I set a minimum then this excludes anyone before this version.

I've received emails from users who have various reasons they are unable to upgrade; some are using previous versions simply because they haven't updated and others because of office politics.

I've known businesses who the last time I've checked are still using IE6. A few times I've seen system requirements increased that excludes previous generation hardware.

I could have found when an API was introduced and check against a version number or I could try to include the class so later I could check a supports flag or check if the class is not null.

Since setting a minimum version would exclude a segment of the audience this way I could support the users who have not updated while still providing users who have updated access to the features using newer APIs.

Approach 1:

```
const system = require("system");

try {
   const foo = require("foo");
}

function performSomeAction() {
    if (supportsFoo) {
       foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
const system = require("system");
var supportsFoo = false;

try {
   const foo = require("foo");
   supportsFoo = true;
}

function start() {
    if (foo) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

In my cases I can't see a catch block being necessary.

**Semantics:**

For my specific case:

```
Try to import a class using require() and
set a constant or variable to that class / api
If an error is thrown skip any other code in the try block and continue
If no error the constant or variable will not be null
In the constructor check for not-null and enable features for use
```

Per a comment below here is test code in JS environment:

```
var x = function() {
    try {
        console.log("hello")
        throw new Error();
        console.log("world");
    }
    // catch(e) {}
    console.log("After try");
}

// VM373:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try
```

**ANOTHER USE CASE (5 days later):**
FWIW in CSS there is the idea of a *`progressive enhancement`*.

Because of the way CSS styles are defined, styles can be defined multiple times and styles of the same name that are added last overwrite values set before it.

So you can have this list of styles like so:

```
body {
   color: red;
   color: blue;
}
```

The color will be blue because it is defined last. That's perfectly valid in CSS. It's not right or wrong it's valid.

So this comes in handy when you want to support progressive features without breaking support for earlier browsers:

```
.slideshow {
    display: flex;
    display: grid;
}
```

In the style declaration above the browser will use a `grid` display if it is supported and if not it will use `flex` display. There is no error thrown for using an incorrect value.

That's the same as:

```
var element = document.getElementById("label");
element.style.setPropertyValue("flex");

try {
    // if the style is not supported the browser retains the value flex
    element.style.setPropertyValue("display", "grid");
} catch(e){ /* no catch is needed */ }
```

You could also write the CSS as:

```
.slideshow {
    display: grid;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
    .slideshow {
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

The code for that would be:

```
var element = document.getElementById("label");
element.style.setPropertyValue("display", "flex");

if (CSS.supports("('display:grid')")) {
    element.style.setPropertyValue("display", "grid");
}
```

In both cases you are defining a variable, attempting to set test / set it to a new value that it may not support.

The first approach is recommended for greatest backwards compatibility:

```
.slideshow {
    display:flex;
    display:grid;
}
```

Granted, when setting styles that are not compatible the browser will retain the previous valid values. I'm banking on this knowledge or this information to determine that a catch block is not necessary. This isn't my use case btw. My use case is in the "long story" section.

Comment: Could you explain why you want a try without a catch-block?

Comment: Can you explain what you want the semantics to be? You have only asked about the syntax so far, but the syntax is the least important part of a programming language. For example: yes, in Ruby, you don't need to use `catch` together with `try`. In fact, you *can't* use `catch` together with `try`. But that is because in Ruby, `try` and `catch` have nothing to do with each other, and neither of the two has anything to do with exceptions.

Comment: I've edited this question to remove the "is there any language that …" part. Those words make it sound a little like a request for resources and so it's attracting close votes. The edit should protect the question from those folk.

Comment: I think he wants it to quietly swallow the exception. The reason there's no shorthand for that is that it's bad practice.

Comment: It might just be me, but the added example code in the update doesn't really clarify anything.

Comment: They do. They typically require a `catch` *or* a `finally` block.

Comment: Java allows try without a catch, as long it is either a try-with-resources or it has a finally block. So your premise seems to be wrong. In any case, if you don't need to catch anything here, why use a try at all?

Comment: @Celos I've updated with more details.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It allows the parser to continue executing whether the class is available or not

Comment: I am probably missing something important in the question but: why do you want to catch the error in the first place, if you do not want to do anything with the fact that the there is an exception? "anything" above includes "doing nothing" (ignoring the exception). So either you know you will have an exception and that you care (in which case you prepare the ground with the try) or you know that you will have an exception and do not care (in which case you do not try/catch anything). But I think I really missed the point of the question.

Comment: @WoJ The way I see it, he uses the error so it skips setting the rest of the variables in the block. Tries to load a new version, if version is there, set boolean to true, if version is absent (which is indicated by the error), keep boolean false.

Comment: @PieterB except you can't reassign `const supportsFoo` so,`supportsFoo = true` will throw an error every single time. The question is not very clear and the added code is not helping matters.

Comment: After reading "The long story", this sounds like entirely the wrong approach. If you want to use a new API, it makes sense that it wouldn't be available on old systems. But the way you go about it is by *splitting your codebase*. You either need to re-implement the functionality yourself for older environments or simply, silently drop the functionality *without* affecting other things. In both cases that leads to parallel implementations you have to maintain.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: "It allows the parser to continue executing whether the class is available or not" – *Again*, you are only talking about *syntax*, when the important thing is the *semantics*, which you have been asked about numerous times and thus far refused to answer. By the way, the *parser* doesn't care one bit whether the class is available or not, the AST will be exactly the same either way. You *need* to specify the *semantics* of the feature you are looking for. And it is not enough to simply throw out examples without any explanation. You need to properly specify the semantics for …

Comment: … *all* possible cases, not just 2 examples. If you are *really* only interested in the *syntax*, then Ruby fits your bill. It doesn't require `catch` together with `try` for the simple reason that `try` and `catch` have nothing to do with each other in Ruby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What do you mean by semantics? Yesterday I came across a case where I thought I need to prevent this error but I don't need to do anything if it errors. I remember hearing and seeing a lot of Java code where that was normal. This was a while ago and was used for testing features. It seemed normal to Java developers. So I found this one case where and I came here and asked if it's possible to have a `try` block without the catch block. Does that help?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: As I wrote before, yes, the syntax you are asking about is definitely possible. I gave an example of a language where `try` can be used without `catch` syntactically, namely Ruby. But, syntax is irrelevant (even though it's what people argue most about), what is relevant is the *semantics*, and you haven't told us what you want the semantics of your hypothetical construct to be. As you can see, people are guessing and hypothesizing and making stuff up and there are at least three different, incompatible, interpretations of your question. You need to specify the semantics.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What do you mean by semantics? Give an example of what semantics mean to you.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If Ruby lets you do this add it as an answer. I understand there are reasons against it. BTW The long story section is my actual real case.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: I am simply using the standard programming language meaning of the term "semantics", which is more or less also the standard English meaning of the term.

Comment: "If Ruby lets you do this add it as an answer." – I have no idea whether or not Ruby lets you "do this", because you still haven't told us what "do this" means. I can tell you that Ruby lets you *syntactically* use `try` without `catch`, for the simple reason that *semantically* `try` and `catch` have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other, but I have no idea whether `try` and `catch` in Ruby have the *semantics* that you are looking for, since you haven't told us what the semantics are. My best guess is that their semantics are *not* what you are looking for, but so far, you …

Comment: … have been *exclusively* focused on *syntax* (**bold** emphasis mine), for example, in this comment: "It allows the **parser** to continue executing". Well, syntax is one thing, obviously, if the code doesn't even parse, it is useless. But the important thing is the *semantics*. What does it *mean*? You haven't told us that. Therefore, I cannot tell you whether or not Ruby fits the bill, since I have no idea what "the bill" is, so to speak.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're not making any sense. I've explained this as best as I can. I've asked you define what semantics are twice (5 comments up and 7 comments up). I don't know what you want to know.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: As I said, I am simply using the standard meaning of the term, nothing special: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: A good way to specify the semantics of what you want to achieve would be explain what changes you would make to [subsection 13.15.8 *Runtime Semantics: Evaluation*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-try-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of [section 13.15 *The `try` Statement*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-try-statement) of [ECMA-262: *ECMAScript Language Specification*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). Especially considering the fact that, as you can see, `try` without `catch` is *already legal* in ECMAScript.

Comment: @JörgWMittag OK I think I understand. I've updated the post.

Comment: OK, so the IE6 thing?  You have *no* responsibility for supporting these people.  Period.  Tell them to get a modern operating system and browser, and welcome them to the 21st century.

Comment: @JörgWMittag When I test some try code in the browser it throws an error. I'll add the code above.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: "*as you can see, try without catch is already legal in ECMAScript.*" That's a pedantic point. Yes, you can have a `try` without `catch`, but you'd have to use `finally`. The point as explained in the question is to not have to type *anything* after the `try` block. The desired code is the very first code example in the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "*OK, so the IE6 thing?*" No, it's not. He merely used that as an example of why someone would want to write this code. Granted, that's not really an excuse for wanting to write it *this way*, but IE6 support is not the point of the question.

Comment: Not super relevant, but read up on the semantics of `const`. Notably, doing a `const x = (whatever)` inside of a block will leave `x` as undefined outside that block because const is block scoped.

Answer (score 61):

> I don't need the catch block.

But you do need to *catch*. The behavior of your code with a catch block is to catch any exception, and then forget that it happened. So any exception that tries to pass through will stop, and your code will basically pretend that the `try` block executed successfully.

So you want a naked `try` block to act like it catches an exception and ignores it. Here's the thing: a default case is meant to be a common case, one that is useful by many users and not error prone. `if` doesn't typically require an `else` because there are many cases where you have nothing to do.

I know nothing about why you want to drop exceptions on the floor and pretend they didn't happen. I'm willing to accept that you have some good justification for doing so. But the fact is, in the *general case*, it's not a good idea. Most programmers don't want to do it, and there are good arguments to say that it is generally unwise to do this sort of thing.

A good language will let you do something unwise. But a good language will not let you do something unwise *by accident*. Since the behavior you want is generally unwise, languages tend to make you explicitly request it.

Comment: FWIW, `if` does require an `else` in Haskell since it's not possible to "do nothing".

Comment: Javas' `try-with` doesn't require a _catch_ block

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but it does have an implicit `finally`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer and it does not catch/ignore exceptions in `try` block as OP wants

Comment: @immibis You're comparing apples and oranges. `if` in Haskell is an *expression*. `if` in most languages is a *statement*. [`when`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832828/haskell-do-nothing-io-or-if-without-else/832838#832838) is a better analog to the `if` statement.

Comment: And the semantics of `if` in Haskell is more like the tenerary `<a> ? <b> : <c>` operator in other languages. Or `if` in Excel.

Comment: The jq data transformation language allows [try without catch](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#try-catch) by assuming a default exception handler

Comment: @MateenUlhaq And it's because `if` is an expression that it's not possible to "do nothing".

Comment: @Nicol In an if else situation you have code you want to run if a statement is true and code you want to run if a statement is not true. In my case, if the API is new enough it will have a library I need. In my case, I'm doing the else code first and setting all the defaults. Then I use a try {} block in case feature X is available to set to some flags. So yes, I want to "try-some-code-and-catch-and-ignore-the-errors". Since I've already set defaults, in my opinion, I don't need the catch block.

Comment: Funnily enough, Rust has both an if-else statement and an if-else expression. But then, it also has some fancy ideas about what an ["expression"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) is.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: "*in my opinion, I don't need the catch block.*" But you are not the only user of the language. So while you personally may do this in a couple of cases, that is not sufficient justification for making it a language *default*. There have been times when I wish some specific thing were a default because it led to me repeating a lot of seemingly unnecessary code. But one person's usage pattern is not enough of a reason to do something. So you might need a few more keystrokes than you might prefer to use. But they exist for a reason, even if you yourself don't need them.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: Or to put it another way, considering how easy it is to *accidentally* implement your kind of `try` block when the user doesn't want to, and considering how dangerous it is in most cases of exception usage... why *should* this feature exist? What justification can you offer besides the fact that it would remove 7 keystrokes from a few places in your code?

Comment: @NicolBolas Indeed (tealc here). But what if I told you 100s of millions of developers use try without catch every day? Is such a thing even possible? Yes it is possible (Ancient Aliens guy from history channel here). I've added that use case in the section entitled "Another Use Case".

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: I don't see any `try` blocks in that CSS at all. "There is no error thrown for using an incorrect value," because the language CSS *explicitly defines it so*. The example you've given is in no way related to an actual programming language that has an actual `try` block that uses actual exception handling. So saying that they "use try without catch every day" is just wrong.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: Also, I don't know JavaScript, but the way I would write it would be `element.style.setPropertyValue("display", CSS.supports("('display:grid')") ? "grid" : "flex");`. I don't know if JavaScript has the `?:` operator, but I'm sure they have something close enough to the general idea.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: And the other thing you have to remember is you only need 10 extra keystrokes. It's hardly an onerous burden, and the time you have spent debating this is probably longer than the time you will spend typing `catch(e){}` for these cases, in total, throughout your *entire programming career*.

Comment: @NicolBolas probably lol.The main reason for the question was being interested in finding out if any languages support it. JavaScript supports the ternary operator, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator but not all browsers support the CSS.supports() command, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports.

Comment: @NicolBolas "I don't see any try blocks in that CSS at all." It's not the try block code it's the concept. _Define the defaults and then try to upgrade if possible._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94040/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-1-21-gigawatts).

Answer (score 34):

As others have pointed out, there are good reasons why a plain `try` is not allowed in JavaScript, or in most other languages that have the same syntax:

- It's not even obvious what it should do: for consistency with `try`...`finally`, a `try` with no `catch` should arguably just let any exceptions through without, well, catching them.  But without a `catch` *or* a `finally` block, such a plain `try` would be useless.
- Most likely, a `try` without a `catch` (or a `finally`) is just an editing mistake, just like an `else` without an `if`.  It's a good thing for the parser to notice and inform you of such mistakes.
- Catching exceptions and ignoring them completely is an unusual and risky thing to do, since it's easy to catch more than you expected.  If you really want to do it, it's a good thing that the language at least forces you to be explicit about it.

In particular, note that your example code is kind of fragile and makes it easy to introduce subtle bugs that can be hard to detect and debug, since everything will *seem* to behave normally.  For instance, let's make the following seemingly harmless change to your example:

```
// setting defaults ahead of try - no need for a catch block?
var setting = 10;
var myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/g");
var supportsRegEx2 = false;

try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
    setting = 20;
    myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/gm");
    supportsRegEx2 = true;
}
catch (e) {} // why does JS force me to do this?
```

Can you see what might go wrong here?  I'll give you a moment to think about it...

OK, so what happens if `optimizeRegEx()` has a bug and crashes when given the input `"/123/gm"`?  That exception will also be caught and ignored, since it happens inside the `try` block, so you'll never see it!  Worse, now your variables will end up in an inconsistent state: `setting` will be 20 and the `applicationutils` module will be loaded, but `myRegEx` will still have its original value and `supportsRegEx2` will be false.  Have fun debugging that!

So how would you do that safely?  Well, the first thing would be to ensure that the variables *always* end up in a consistent state, at least.  One way to do that would be to (re)set them to their defaults in the `catch` block:

```
// these will be set inside the try/catch block below
var setting, myRegEx, supportsRegEx2;

try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
    setting = 20;
    myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/gm");
    supportsRegEx2 = true;
}
catch (e) {
    // something went wrong, probably require() failed: use fallback defaults instead
    setting = 10;
    myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/g");
    supportsRegEx2 = false;
}
```

That's a bit better: any exceptions from `optimizeRegEx("/123/gm")` will still be silently thrown away, but at least all the variables will end up with their default values if that happens.

Even better would be to fix the code to *only* catch the specific exception thrown when the `require()` fails.  Unfortunately JavaScript makes this harder than it should be, since it doesn't support conditional `catch` clauses.  But we can at least follow the general principle of having as little code as possible inside each `try` to avoid catching unexpected exceptions, and we can also inspect the caught exception inside the `catch` block and rethrow it if it's not what we expected to see:

```
// setting defaults ahead of try
var setting = 10;
var myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/g");
var supportsRegEx2 = false;

// try loading utils, catch and ignore module loading error
var utils = null;
try {
    utils = require("applicationutils");
}
catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') throw e;  // rethrow any unexpected errors
}

// adjust variables if the module loaded without errors
if (utils !== null) {
    setting = 20;
    myRegEx = optimizeRegEx("/123/gm");
    supportsRegEx2 = true;
}
```

<sup>(Error code test based on [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197795/handle-errors-thrown-by-require-module-in-node-js/38885374#38885374).)</sup>

Now we're only ignoring those errors that come from the statement that we *expect* to throw them and which also *look* like the error we expect.  This minimizes the risk of us accidentally ignoring an error that *wasn't* the harmless one we were expecting, and thus makes the code more robust and easier to debug.

---

Regarding your actual use case (now that you've described it), it seems to me that what you *really* want is a wrapper function like this:

```
function tryRequire(moduleName) {
    try {
        return require(moduleName);
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (e.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') return null;  // adjust this as needed to detect module loading errors in your environment
        throw e;  // rethrow any unexpected errors
    }
}
```

This way, you can just do `const foo = tryRequire('foo')`, and then check whether the module was successfully loaded based on whether `foo` is null.

Comment: Good answer with great examples that demonstrate why ignoring exceptions is a bad idea, and therefore doesn't have a syntax that makes it easier. OP should consider using the advice in this answer to refactor his code.

Comment: "*easy to introduce subtle bugs*" funny you predicted that - OP added an example of what he wants to do and has *exactly* this subtle bug you talked about here. The intention is to try and load a module `"foo"`, if successful, to set `supportsFoo` to `true`. However, that variable is declared as `const`, so re-assigning it will throw an error...which OP wants to implicitly and silently ignore. Thus the code would work but would always claim that `supportsFoo` is `false`, even if loading the module succeeded. Case in point why you want to be specific and explicit with error handling.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. Ilmari makes a good point. But I would have caught that during normal development during the part where you test code immediately after you write it. Or the compiler would have flagged reassignment of a const. All development can be said to be, "easy to introduce subtle bugs." but yes, good points. I've updated the code to use var instead of const.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts “I would have caught that during normal development” - I have found that every time I have this mindset I introduce a bug that is caught in production in a spectacularly embarrassing fashion.

Answer (score 9):

Many languages permit: `try { ... } finally { ... }` or some variant. Take C# as an example. There are plenty of others.

But there is no point in a `try { ... }`. It has no meaning without an associated:

- `catch(...) { ... }`
- `finally { ... }`
- `catch(...) { ... } finally { ... }`.
- `catch(...) { ... } catch(...) { ... } ... catch(...) { ... }`.

The use case you are highlighting is actually very bad code.

If you are expecting an error, and you do nothing about it, your design is fundamentally flawed.

You could say that this syntax is working as expected. Because it is irritating you enough to look for a solution.

The solution is to either get rid of the `try` altogether, or figure out how to handle the error.

Comment: "There is no point to a try {}". Hmm... "There's never a use case for it and so it's bad code?" You don't know enough about the situation to know that. Should every if statement have an else statement? The compiler throws errors when you encounter a class you want to import that doesn't exist but you have to import it to use it. I'll add more code.

Comment: `try {} finally {}` won't suppress the exception though, it'll get raised in the caller. It seems the OP wants to suppress all exceptions.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: Exactly what behavior do you want, then? There are only two things that I could imagine happening in this case. The exception gets caught, consumed and dropped; or the exception passes through your code and out into the caller like normal.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts the reason we don't know about the situation because you've not explained. There is no logical reason to have `try` without any handling there - you may as well drop the `try` block entirely. After all, you don't want to specify what happens when an exception crops up, so the most constistent thing a computer can infer from "try running this code. The are no special instructions for if it fails" is to run the code and if it fails to just propagate the exception as normal. Which makes the code pointless. Similar to how `if (true) const val = 1` in JS with no block is pointless.

Comment: "Should every `if` statement have an `else` statement?" That's not really a good analogy. Look at the `catch` block as corresponding to the "then" part of an `if` statement. A `try` without a `catch` is like writing `if (predicate) {}`.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: (1) If we don't know about the situation, then your question is not well formed. (2) An if without an else has a purpose. A try without a catch does not. Try merely defines the scope in which the catching needs to occur. Without a catch, there's no point to defining a scope in which to catch an exception. (3) Just because you don't do anything with the caught exception does not mean that you don't need to catch it. (4) You are essentially asking why a certain syntax doesn't do what you want it to implicitly do. Implicit expectations are vague and subjective, not a good approach

Comment: @Flater I've updated the question with more details (long story section).

Answer (score 4):

What would that mean?

I would expect:

```
try {
    const utils = require("applicationutils");
}
```

To mean the same thing as:

```
const utils = require("applicationutils");
```

try/catch/finally is a well understood pattern, used in a lot of different languages.  Exceptions by their very nature imply that there is a recovery handler somewhere else.

It sounds like what you are looking for is VB’s On Error Resume Next, which catches and ignores errors on a line by line basis.  Today this is generally considered a bad practice, because it means that there is no actual error handling going on — flow continues as if the previous line had succeeded, which can lead to escalating the level of garbage/damage that is done by bad input, instead of halting or eliminating just the bad input.

The try/catch pattern is useful, because it can segment your algorithm into parts where you can fail but recover, and parts where there is no recovery after failure.  And in the event that there is no recovery after failure, it is **that** part that cannot continue not the rest of the application.

If you have a need for this in js, you could get the same effect, by creating a function that takes a function as it’s argument, wraps it in a  executes it inside a try catch block where it just sets an error object.  You could then use lambda expressions for any line you would like to resume next on.

```
var err = {}
var ex = function(action){
             try {
                 action()
             }
             catch (e) {
                 err=e
             }
         }
 var i =5
 ex(t=> alert(i.foo()))
 console.log(i)
 console.log(err.message)
```

Although it won’t work with lines that declare and initialize variables.

Comment: Look at the example on the question. OP does not want `setting`, `myRegEx` and `supportsRegEx2` to be modified if `require` fails. It is not a simple `On Error Resume Next`. It would be more like `On Error Goto Label`. Addendum: ultimately what OP wants is to omit `catch(e) {}` but have it behave exactly as if it were there.

Comment: Of note: that block scope is *important* because of the semantics of `const`. Notably, `const x = require("anything")` will result in `x` as the module after execution, but `try{const x = require("anything")}catch(e){}` will result in `x` being `undefined` after execution, since const is block-scoped - the fact that you left a block is important (it also depends on whether you're in strict mode).

Comment: I refer to the [version of May 17 at 1:39](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/391999/3), your answer is date at May 17 at 3:15.

Answer (score 3):

No, no language support this syntax. The closest I know is VB's `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` which kind of does what you want: It ignores any exception and just continue on the next line.

So why doesn't languages support this? Because it is very vare rare you need it in a well-designed program. Usually a missing catch or finally would indicate the programmer forgot it, so the syntax is a safeguard.

In the very rare case where you want to just ignore exceptions you can use an empty catch block with a comment explaining why you ignore exceptions here. This signals the intentions much better. If you are doing something really uncommon and potential dangerous, then it is good style to communicate clearly in the code that you know what you are doing (and why).

Answer (score 2):

Swift allows try without catch. There are four ways in Swift to handle exceptions: 1. The usual way with try and catch. 2. By using "try?" on a method call returning a result of type T, which means you get a result of type Optional, and the result is nil if the call did throw an exception. 3. By using "try!", which means your application crashes if an exception is thrown, and 4. by making a call in a method that is itself throwing.